# How to create button click function

Tags: php

I created button click function in php and it won't print.

```
//create button click
if(isset($_POST['create'])){
    echo "created button clicked";
}
```

Please help, thanks, Jacky

Comment: Sounds like `$_POST['create']` probably isn't set.  Or anything else could be wrong with code you're not showing us.  Can you provide a more complete example?

Comment: Hi, please give us more details, how is your click triggered, is it Ajax, Form submit, page load. What is sending your $_POST

Comment: This is PHP/HTML 101 and there are literally hundreds of tutorials online. Please take some basic PHP tutorials, perhaps at someplace like Codecademy

Comment: Have you added `name="create"` to your create button?

Comment: @David, In my index.php, I called button element like this : <?php buttonElement("btn-create", "btn btn-success","<i class='fas fa-plus'></i>","create","dat-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='bottom' title='create'");?>, if this can help, thanks, Jacky

Comment: @NewProgrammer: What is `buttonElement()`?  What HTML code does that generate?  How are you posting your form?  Please add code and details to the question, not in comments.

Comment: Is `buttonElement()` a custom function or from a framework?

Comment: function buttonElement($btnid,$styleclass,$text,$name,$attr){
    $btn="
    <button name='name''$attr' class='$styleclass' id='$btnid'>$text</button>
    ";
    echo $btn;
}

Comment: @NewProgrammer: According to that line of code, the name of your button would be `name`, not `create`.  So `$_POST['create']` wouldn't be set, but `$_POST['name']` would be.  You can debug/confirm this by examining the HTML that your code outputs to the browser, or clarify the code in the question.

Comment: @david, you are the best, problem solved! yes, I changed the create to name and it works perfectly. Thank you David and all!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a form, and then actually `POST` the data through to your script.

This will `POST` the data through to the script that the form is on:

```
<form method="POST">
   <input type="submit" name="create" value="Click Me" />
</form>
```

Have that in your page as the button your want to click, when you click it, it will `POST` `$_POST['create']` so you will reach your `echo` statement.

Also, use `array_key_exists()`:

```
if(array_key_exists('create', $_POST)){
    echo "created button clicked";
}
```

You don't need to check if there is a value, which there may not be depending on how you're doing your button, but you do need to check that the array key exists in the `$_POST` array.